# When should you use a front-end framework like Angular or React, and when just use plain HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: reactjs, angular, frameworks, frontend, development-environment

I know that for a simple static website, using plain HTML.. is the easiest and quickest way. But, what are some use cases between the two options? Is using a framework mostly the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can basically see frameworks as pre-written structures for your App.

In other words, frameworks are meant to help you building applications quicker by addressing common development problems.

So, going back to your question, there are not really times where you would prefer vanilla javascript over frontend frameworks due to the incapacity of scaling well, which could result in inscrutable and unmaintainable [spaghetti code](https://www.hackterms.com/spaghetti%20code).

Other bit you would want to consider about frameworks, is their high performance obtained thanks to their [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) (abstract map of the real DOM), which helps handling events to update parts of the App without the need of re-rendering it.

On the other hand, I would suggest to go with a static website using pure HTML and Vanilla JS, only if learning / instructing someone, or if building something really really simple (but rest assure 99% of your commercial websites may suit better under a framework rather than without).

If you want to read more about it, I would suggest the following articles:

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/03/is-it-time-for-a-front-end-framework/
- https://gomakethings.com/why-do-people-choose-frameworks-over-vanilla-js/
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/do-we-still-need-javascript-frameworks-42576735949b/